# unity , Failed to re-package resources?

Tags: c#, android, ios, android-layout, unity-game-engine

Im trying to add admob to my game project, but every time trying to build apk the problem appears.

*I'm using unity 5.3.5 and admob plugin 3.0.3*

> Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package
>   resources. See the Console for details.
>   D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe
>   package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S
>   "res" -I

Comment: can you please post the full error details shown in the console.

Comment: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:com.google.firebase.unity:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable -S